# For a first order system, what type of response to a sine wave?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, transfer-function, laplace-transform

If I put a sine wave through a first order system and reconstruct it with some type of weighting (equal or not), how should the response come out?

Should the response follow the original sine wave almost perfectly, or should it not reach the peak amplitude of the input?

I'm thinking it shouldn't follow the original perfectly since there's a time constant required to reach the peak?

Comment: Define "almost perfectly". Depending on the system and the sine wave the output could be equal to the input "almost perfectly". For example, a low pass filter with cutoff frequency 1MHz and a gain of 1 should pass a 1kHz sine wave "almost perfectly".

Comment: If you put a sinewave thru any filter and reconstruct it (as in make it the same?) then it's going to be a sinewave again.

Comment: What does 'reconstruct' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first order system will produce an output which is also a sine, but with a different amplitude and phase. Because the differential of a sine is also a (phase shifted) sine of the same period, and the output of a first order system is a sum of the input and the differential of the input, there is no other possibility - you are adding two sines with the same period and that can only result in amplitude and phase change, not a non-sinusoid.

Once you start considering slew rates and other limits, you no longer have a linear first order system, so it may be distorted. Given a slew rate, and the first order equation, you can determine the frequency that linearity breaks down from the maximal gradient of a signal of given amplitude.

Comment: It's more general than that: *any* linear, time-invariant (LTI) system will have a sinewave response to a sinewave stimulus.

Comment: Assuming it is stable :-).